# How to check memory of a Windows machine, in order to solve pagefile issues

Tags: windows, memory, performance

One of my customers has a Windows machine, who is using far too much resources writing and reading the pagefile. As the pagefile is used for handling exceeding RAM demand, this makes me think that there is a problem with the RAM of that machine.

However this machine is just one of a whole bunch of machines, running equal software on similar data.

So I'm wondering if there might be any other issues, like a problem with the processors of the machine.

I'm having quite some experience working with UNIX machines, and there there are commands like `chkdsk`, `psrinfo`, `vmstat`, ... for monitoring the health of the machine.

Is there a Windows equivalent for `psrinfo` or `prstat`, which I might use for checking the health of the hardware of the mentioned machine? Or:
Which report should I create in the performance monitor in order to confirm whether or not a hardware problem is the root cause of this issue?

Comment: If you suspect RAM, the same diagnostic tools, which are OS independent, can be used.

Comment: What is wrong with the typical solution `memtestx86`?  There are memory testing tools built into Windows, but the traditional solution of `memtestx86`, is a better solution

Comment: check memory usage with RAMMap to see how Windows uses the RAM. slowness doesn't mean the ram is damaged.

Comment: Thanks for the first quick comments. About `memtestx86`: I can run a simple tool or program on that machine, but `memtestx86` requires full installation and restart, so that's not an option. About RAMMap: as I mentioned the machine has equal installation/configuration as another machine, but the pagefile usage is very high, so we believe something being wrong with the hardware itself (and in case there's no hardware problem, it would be nice to be sure we can rule this out).

Comment: without knowing how RAM is used we can't help you. so run RAMmap and compare the data between the good and bad system to find why one windows pages more compared to the other

Answer (score 1):

I got directed to this question when searching for an equivalent command for "vmstat" on Windows.

Thought of leaving a possible answer that I got from another web page at : https://coderanch.com/t/132107/engineering/Windows-XP-NT-vmstat-functionality

This might come in handy for anyone who might visit this question for similar reasons as me.

- `ps` can be simulated through `tasklist`
- `vmstat` can be simulated through `logman` and `typeperf`

P.S : I have not tried these commands on my own. Also, the reference link I gave above has been written more than a decade ago. So, later versions of Windows might have other solutions as well.